# Boost thread c2064 error when trying to compile

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, boost

I'm quite new to the stack overflow, in fact this is my first post, So hello everyone. So let's get to the point.
Using boost library thread ver. 1.54.0
Using VS2010 32 Bit - Professional
I have built the libraries for the boost thread,
not using precompiled headers in vs C++ settings,
linked the library to the project,
here is the code

```
    #include <boost\thread\thread_only.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib")
#define BOOST_LIB_NAME libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib


struct callable
{
     void blah();
};

void callable::blah()
{
    std::cout << "Threading test !\n";
}
boost::thread createThread()
{
    callable x;
    return boost::thread(x);
}
int main()
{
    createThread();
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

after all this I get this error

```
Error   1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments    ..\..\boost_1_54_0\boost\thread\detail\thread.hpp   117 1   BoostTrial
```

Could you help me to get this example to work. Reason why I am using this example is because I have another app which has been set up exactly the same way and it's not working because of this error :-( my goal is to get the multithreading to work and then I can take it from there.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: By guess is, `callable` needs to implement an `operator()()`, not a function named `blah` (or anything else). How do you expect the library to know which name to use? It likely just does `x()` - hence the error.

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik. +1 for you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `operator()` in `callable`.

Don't forget to either `join()` or `detach()` thread to prevent abnormal program termination.

See [`boost::thread` tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial) for more examples.

```
#include <boost\thread\thread_only.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib, "libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_54.lib")

using namespace boost;

struct callable
{
    void operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "Threading test !\n";
    }
};


boost::thread createThread()
{
    callable x;
    return boost::thread(x);
}
int main()
{
    boost::thread th = createThread();
    th.join();

}
```

[Example with `std::thread`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4d22b971ccfaeb5);

Comment: Thanks @Drop! +1 for you. I wanted to say thanks to both of you in previous comment but I can't notify more than one user :-p.